# iPhone camera not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Camera is not showing when a view loads. Instead it shows the view I designed. The code works well when it is given inside a button action.
Can any one help? Code is as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
    scroll_under.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1000,50);
    if(scroll_under.contentOffset.x==0)
    {   
        leftArrow.hidden=TRUE;
    }
    if(scroll_under.contentOffset.x==429)
    {
        rightArrow.hidden=TRUE;
    }
    if(scroll_under.contentOffset.x>0 && scroll_under.contentOffset.x<429)
    {
        leftArrow.hidden=FALSE;
        rightArrow.hidden=FALSE;        
    }
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;         
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
    resultImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Comment: i know this is a silly question, but just to make sure - are working in the simulator? Check for `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]` boolean value before the camera code there

Comment: Its not working on both simulator and device

Answer (score 1):

to make it work, just move your code to :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;         
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: let the controller present it's view before presenting another controller.

Comment: No it wont help i'm getting the same result as before

Comment: just to make it run (precondition-your code was working on button click), put the code in a separate method and use [self performSelector:@selector(method) afterDelay:0.5];

Comment: It worked but still the view is first seen and then only the modal view controller works. What can be done for that.

Comment: what i suggested was a immediate workaround. it is not a proper solution. you can meanwhile use the same with setting "afterDelay:0];" and keep figuring out what's the actual problem with your code.